# Counter-Strike: Source not launching

Tags: lubuntu, games

I am running 64-bit Lubuntu 15.10. I have Counter-Strike: Source installed on my system and attempting to run it give an error.

```
SDL video target is 'x11'
SDL video target is 'x11'
SDL failed to create GL compatibility profile (whichProfile=0)!
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_EXT_framebuffer_object.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample.
This system DOES NOT support the OpenGL extension GL_APPLE_fence.
This system DOES NOT support the OpenGL extension GL_NV_fence.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_ARB_sync.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_EXT_draw_buffers2.
This system DOES NOT support the OpenGL extension GL_EXT_bindable_uniform.
This system DOES NOT support the OpenGL extension GL_APPLE_flush_buffer_range.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_ARB_map_buffer_range.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_ARB_occlusion_query.
This system DOES NOT support the OpenGL extension GL_APPLE_texture_range.
This system DOES NOT support the OpenGL extension GL_APPLE_client_storage.
This system DOES NOT support the OpenGL extension GL_ARB_uniform_buffer.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_ARB_framebuffer_object.
This system DOES NOT support the OpenGL extension GL_GREMEDY_string_marker.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_ARB_debug_output.
This system DOES NOT support the OpenGL extension  GL_EXT_direct_state_access.
This system DOES NOT support the OpenGL extension GL_NV_bindless_texture.
This system DOES NOT support the OpenGL extension GL_AMD_pinned_memory.
This system supports the OpenGL extension     GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample_blit_scaled.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode.
This system DOES NOT support the OpenGL extension GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info.
This system DOES NOT support the OpenGL extension GL_ATI_meminfo.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5.
This system DOES NOT support the OpenGL extension GLX_EXT_swap_control_tear.
GL_NV_bindless_texture: DISABLED
GL_AMD_pinned_memory: DISABLED
GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode: AVAILABLE
AppFramework : Unable to load module vguimatsurface.so!
Unable to load interface VGUI_Surface030 from vguimatsurface.so
```

I am not using Steam. Things I have tried:

```
sudo apt-get install fontconfig:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386 libxi6:i386 libnss3:i386 libpango1.0-0:i386 libpng3:i386 libasound2:i386 libcairo2:i386 libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 libsdl2-gfx-1.0-0:i386 libgcrypt11:i386
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

[`glxinfo` output](http://pastebin.com/3AjeYnrU)

I have resolved this by simply using Wine to run the Windows version. Thank you all very much.

Comment: Looks like your computer doesn't support the required OpenGL extensions. What graphics card do you have?

Comment: Pentium G3220 integrated graphics.

Comment: Sorry, doesn't look like your computer meets the requirements for CS:GO. The minimum for graphics is: nVidia GeForce 8600/9600GT, ATI/AMD Radeon HD2600/3600 (Graphic Drivers: nVidia 310, AMD 12.11), OpenGL 2.1

Comment: But this is source, not global offensive.

Comment: Oops, looks like I screwed up big time there, my bad. Interestingly, Steam didn't have the graphics specs for Linux. However, the Windows and Mac specs are very similar, so it's still likely that you need better graphics hardware.

Comment: It requires a " DirectX® 8.1 level Graphics Card ".  According to http://ark.intel.com/products/77773/Intel-Pentium-Processor-G3220-3M-Cache-3_00-GHz it should support that.

Comment: DirectX is A Windows-only feature, but your processor supports OpenGL 4, which should be adequate. Unless the game can only run on Nvidia or AMD... This is the point where I'd suggest installing proprietary drivers, but my knowledge of that is only on Nvidia.

Comment: I can confirm that the intel graphics drivers are installed. xserver-xorg-video-intel is the package name.

Comment: In response to your edit, there isn't proprietary drivers. That one is the offical driver, and is free.

Comment: According to your `glxinfo` output, your graphics adapter only support OpenGL 3: `OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 11.0.2`.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this myself by simply using Wine for the Windows version. Thank you all for your help though.